# how to Send & symbol in xml body to server

Tags: php, html, asp.net, ios, iphone

I am trying to send the `&` symbol to the server in an XML body but only received a blank.
I tried HTML code to send this also but in vain.

Comment: try unicode for these...

Comment: have you looked at using &#38; or U+0026. You need to use utf8 encoding

Comment: I am using `NSUTF8Encoding`and tried &#38 U+0026 &amp but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a category on `NSString` and then encode few characters that you cant send directly... few are implemented below:

```
@implementation NSString (URLEncoding)

- (NSString *) stringByUrlEncoding{
    return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,  (CFStringRef)self,  NULL,  (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&;=+$,/?%#[]",  kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
}

@end
```