# From NSString to escaped chars in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, encoding

I am not sure if I am asking the right question, please correct me if I'm wrong, but I've searched everywhere and I can't find an answer to help me with the following issue:

I have a NSString with the following content: "Björn Br. Björnsson"

and I need to get it to the following form: "Bj\u00f6rn Br. Bj\u00f6rnsson".

I've tried everything I found related on stackoverflow so far. If anyone has any idea how to get from ö type of characters to \u00f6 it would be awesome.

I have tried:

```
        NSString *name = @"Björn Br. Björnsson";

        NSString* string = [NSString stringWithCString:[name cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

or

```
      NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:name];
      const char *encoded = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

or

```
        NSData* nsData = [name dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        const char* data = [nsData bytes];
        NSUInteger len = nsData.length;
        NSMutableString* hex = [NSMutableString string];
        for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)[hex appendFormat:@"%02X", data[i]];
```

or

```
        const char * encodedStringName = [crewmemName cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

and many other..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094023/how-to-send-symbol-in-xml-body-to-server/20094309#20094309

Comment: Why do you need that output? - If your intention is to create JSON data, then use `NSJSONSerialization` instead of hacking with character encodings etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a category on `NSString` and call this method, this will encode to your desired way

```
@implementation NSString (URLEncoding)

- (NSString *) stringByUrlEncoding{
    return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,  (CFStringRef)self,  NULL,  (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&;=+$,/?%#[]",  kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        NSString *name = @"Björn Br. Björnsson";

name =[name stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"ö" withString:@"\u00f6"];
```

You may have to escape the backslash. Just type \\\ instead of \. But not sure about that.

Comment: I can't do that. I have many other issues like that. can't take them all by hand, I don't even know all the characters that will occur during the existence of the app.

Comment: in this case you should go with @Anoop Vaidya's answer